# Angularjs - http get template with ng model, but result undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to build a page with a dynamic component. Here is my index (left side part) generated by php.

```
<div id="userList" ng-controller="userCtr">
    <div class="user" data-ng-init="userID[0] = 1" ng-click="selectUser(1)">Tom</div>
    <div class="user" data-ng-init="userID[1] = 2" ng-click="selectUser(2)">Peter</div>
    <div class="user" data-ng-init="userID[2] = 3" ng-click="selectUser(3)">Zoe</div>
</div>

<div id="mainView"> {{ mainView }} </div>
```

My template /userAPI/1 is here:

```
<div id="userProfile" ng-init="currentUser = 'Peter'"></div>
<div class="row" ng-model="height">180</div>
<div class="row" ng-model="size">M</div>
<div class="row" ng-model="age">18</div>
```

userCtr try to catch the userID and get the user profile and show in right hand side.

```
userApp.controller("userCtr",  function ($scope) {

    $scope.currentUser = false;
    $scope.height= false;
    $scope.size= false;
    $scope.age= false;
    $scope.selectedUserID = false; 

    $scope.$watch('selectedUserID ', function(){
        var userID = $scope.selectedUserID ;

        if(userID !== false){
            $.get("/userAPI/" + userID).then(function(html){
                 $scope.mainView = html; 

                 /* These return undefined */
                 console.log($scope.height);
                 console.log($scope.size);
                 console.log($scope.age);
                 /* These return undefined */

            });
        ); 
    });     
    $scope.selectUser = function(userID){
        $scope.selectedUserID = userID;
    }

    $scope.$watch('userID', function () {
        if(!$scope.selectedUserID )
            $scope.selectUser ($scope.userID[0]);
    });                
})
```

I am trying to handle the ng-model value in userCtr, but it return undefined when using console.log().
How can I fix that?

Comment: I recommend for this type of nested view prefer using ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Do you mean $scope.mainView is undefined?

Comment: @digit I mean the variable in inserted template. height, size, age.

Comment: Can you put the breakpoint in your code where it is return undefined?

Comment: @digit those variables do not exist in $scope, are those variables in html text file cannot access the $scope?

Comment: From where does the value of height, size, age gets initialized?

Comment: @SubhraJyotiLahiri it return false when I added into controller.

Comment: @TszHin Ma: From where are you expecting the variables to get the values, you have showed in the HTML??